# iPhone gps map draw

Tags: iphone

i am developing a iphone app which will be used by marathon runners.
in that application which is based on GPS i need to draw the running path(something like a line) on the map based on start and stop point of the runner's GPS locations.
I am pretty new to app development, would be great if any of you can guide me on this or help with some code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `Google-Map-API` to get the polyline from google by adding starting and stoping points latitude and longitude. This is the [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) for the API.

And this is the api url:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=starting_address&destination=destination_address&sensor=false
```

And for reference to create polyline see [Mapkit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKit_Framework_Reference/_index.html) doc, and this project from github....
[nvpolyline](https://github.com/wlach/nvpolyline),
[route-me](https://github.com/route-me/route-me),
[mapLines](https://github.com/psholtz/iOS/tree/master/MapLines),
[MapKit-Route-Directions](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/MapKit-Route-Directions)